# How many documents can I index in Solr server in one add() call?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I wrote an application indexing documents on a Solr server. When I try to add some hundreds, everything works fine, but when I try to index the whole content of the database (some 4500 documents) in one `SolrDocument.add()`, call, nothing is actually indexed. Any idea?

Comment: Which version of Solr do you use? Solr 4.x or below?

Comment: Do you get any error? Are you sure that you didn't change the auto commit parameters at solrconfig.xml? Also read here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Enabling_Longer_Query_Requests

Comment: Try batches of 500 onwards, actually any batch size that is not likely to give `500 internal server errors`

Comment: Since the actual problem turned out to be nothing to do with the number of documents added, this Question / Answer is unlikely to be helpful to other people.  Voted to delete as "Too Localized".

Comment: @Stephen C: That's fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea?

Check the solr logs.  It maybe that adding too many documents in one go is causing Solr to over-allocate memory and triggering an OOME.

If that is the problem, the fix is simple.  Don't do it.  Index the documents in batches ... which you know works.  Alternatively, increase the heap size of whatever it is that is OOME'ing.

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of thing I will try, but I just wanted some info about known issues in that matter.

Answer (score 2):

You can add as many documents with Solr Server add method, these documents are just added but not commited to the solr index. Call the commit method to make the changes available in the index and hence available for the searchers.

Answer (score 0):

Several lists were added to the core, some of them empty. As the documents on the core were deleted before the add, the result was: no data on the server. I rewrote completly the indexation of the application and it's working fine, now.

Always be careful if you sanitize the indexed data on your server when you index documents...

Obviously, if there is some limit to the amount of documents you can ad in one time on a Solr server, 4568 is below it.